# Entity set assigned to datagridview will disable sorting

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, datagridview

I use Entity Framework. When I bind an entity set to a standard DataGridView control I lose sort-by-click-on-header functionality. I even tried to bind the entity set to a binding source first but results are the same.

Also if I try to sort a column from code I even get an exception that an interface is not implemented... Are standard EF classes un-sortable (would be a bummer)? Needless to say, sorting works if a DataView is provided as data source.

How could I get around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Nobody have ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but thought I'd at least post an answer... There are two ways to achieve this with little fuss (actually the same method, just slightly different route).

So we have a basic EF context query, pre-execution.

```
var query = context.Projects
    .Where(x => x.Division == selectedDivision);
```

Load the query so entities are in the local cache. Then point the DGV's binding source to the Local cache's synced BindingList

```
query.Load();
projectBindingSource.DataSource = context.Projects.Local.ToBindingList();
```

OR... There were times when I didn't want/need change tracking or the cache "got in the way" of other operations so I needed a non-tracked collection.

Execute the query without tracking and load it's result into an ObservableCollection (Which is what .Local is). Point the DGV's binding source to the ObservableCollection's synced BindingList

```
var locs = new ObservableCollection<Location>(query.AsNoTracking().ToList());
locationBindingSource.DataSource = locs.ToBindingList();
```

All text, numeric, and bool columns will have sort enable for header-click. What won't sort are columns for Navigation Properties: Say a Project has an Owner navigation property, since I have Owner entity's ToString() override display the Owner.FullName property I will see an Owner column with the FullName value but I *assume* the sorter still sees the column's type as the System.Data.Entity object (instead of the bubble up text that is displayed) so doesn't have a default sorter for it.

Comment: Seems interesting. We have DevExpress so we went that route as it works straight away. But I'll definitely check out your ideas. Thanks for returning to this old question (the party's never over :)).